# In Mongo, how can I use $IN condition with values coming from another field?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Data :

```
{
_id :1111,
col1_array : ['a','b','c'],
col2_array : ['a','f','g']
}
```

I would like to find all documents where col2_array contains any value of col1_array. I tried using the $IN condition but failed to refer to other field content as an array. How can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally resolved the problem using arrays intersections I have just discovered digging Mongo documentation :

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
{$set : {
    commonValues: { $setIntersection: [ "$col1_array", "$col2_array"]},
}},
{$match : {"commonValues" : {"$ne" : []}}}

])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$col2_array" },
    {
        $project:
        {
            index: { $indexOfArray: ["$col1_array", "$col2_array"] },
            col2_array: 1,
            col1_array: 1,
            _id: 1
        }
    },
    { $match: { index: { $gte: 0 } } },
    { $group: { _id: "$_id" } }
])
```

After that you have to find records of this particular _id

```
db.collection.find({_id:{$in:[result_of_above_query_ids]}})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but I have finally found another way to do it using array intersections i have just discovered.